# I want to remove the PyAutogui library from my code and use the Pynput library

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, optimization, pynput

I am working on a project which does the work of controlling the cursor, basically virtually controlling the functionality of a mouse(move cursor, scroll up, scroll down, right click, left click). I've used the PyAutoGui for performing these above actions but now want to remove its use and use the pynput library instead. I am posting the part of the code which is responsible for the actions.

```
def performAction(yp, rc, bc, action, drag, perform):
    if perform:
        cursor[0] = 4*(yp[0]-110)
        cursor[1] = 4*(yp[1]-120)
        if action == 'move':
            if yp[0] > 110 and yp[0] < 590 and yp[1] > 120 and yp[1] < 390:
                pyautogui.moveTo(cursor[0], cursor[1])
            elif yp[0] < 110 and yp[1] > 120 and yp[1] < 390:
                pyautogui.moveTo(8, cursor[1])
            elif yp[0] > 590 and yp[1] > 120 and yp[1] < 390:
                pyautogui.moveTo(1912, cursor[1])
            elif yp[0] > 110 and yp[0] < 590 and yp[1] < 120:
                pyautogui.moveTo(cursor[0], 8)
            elif yp[0] > 110 and yp[0] < 590 and yp[1] > 390:
                pyautogui.moveTo(cursor[0], 1072)
            elif yp[0] < 110 and yp[1] < 120:
                pyautogui.moveTo(8, 8)
            elif yp[0] < 110 and yp[1] > 390:
                pyautogui.moveTo(8, 1072)
            elif yp[0] > 590 and yp[1] > 390:
                pyautogui.moveTo(1912, 1072)
            else:
                pyautogui.moveTo(1912, 8)
        elif action == 'left':
            pyautogui.click(button='left')
        elif action == 'right':
            pyautogui.click(button='right')
            time.sleep(0.3)
        elif action == 'up':
            pyautogui.scroll(5)
#           time.sleep(0.3)
        elif action == 'down':
            pyautogui.scroll(-5)                           
#           time.sleep(0.3)
        elif action == 'drag' and drag == 'true':
            global y_pos
            drag = 'false'
            pyautogui.mouseDown()
            while(1):
                k = cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF
                changeStatus(k)
                _, frameinv = cap.read()
                # flip horizontaly to get mirror image in camera
                frame = cv2.flip(frameinv, 1)
                hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
                b_mask = makeMask(hsv, blue_range)
                r_mask = makeMask(hsv, red_range)
                y_mask = makeMask(hsv, yellow_range)
                py_pos = y_pos
                b_cen = drawCentroid(frame, b_area, b_mask, showCentroid)
                r_cen = drawCentroid(frame, r_area, r_mask, showCentroid)
                y_cen = drawCentroid(frame, y_area, y_mask, showCentroid)
                if py_pos[0] != -1 and y_cen[0] != -1:
                    y_pos = setCursorPos(y_cen, py_pos)
                performAction(y_pos, r_cen, b_cen, 'move', drag, perform)
                cv2.imshow('Frame', frame)
                if distance(y_pos, r_cen) > 60 or distance(y_pos, b_cen) > 60 or distance(r_cen, b_cen) > 60:
                    break

            pyautogui.mouseUp()
```

It would be very helpful if I can get a way of removing functionality of the PyAutoGui library and depend solely upon the Pynput library. Please help me out with the necessary changes in the code.\

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please update us with what you’ve tried.

Comment: @barny i've tried changing the library to pynput and also changed the corresponding pyautogui.moveTo to pynput.moveTo

Comment: Those changes don’t appear in your code i your question.